# regarding the concept of dual cone

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

When studying the covex analysis, I am not clear about the concept of `dual cone`. In the following graph, $\mathcal{K}*$ was the dual cone. I marked two points, the read one is supposed to satisfy the inequality of $y^{T}x\leq 0$, where $x$ is represented as the green point. How can we guarantee that this inequatlity is satisfied, and where do thoes $90^{0}$ come from?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a fixed vector $y$, the set $\{x : y^Tx =  0\}$ is a line perpendicular to $x$, which I'll denote $y^\perp$ for brevity. (Dot product of two vectors is zero if and only if they are perpendicular.) This is the source of 90 degree angles you see on the diagram. The line $y^\perp$ divides the plane into two halfplanes. One of which, $\{x : y^Tx \ge  0\}$, is the one we are interested in.

In order for $y$ to belong to the dual cone, we must have $y^Tx\ge 0$ for all $x\in K$. This means precisely that $K$ must be contained in the halfplane $\{x : y^Tx \ge  0\}$. (Consider this logic carefully).

So, in order to test vector $y$ on being in $K^*$, we draw the line $y^\perp$   and check whether all of $K$ is on the same side of $y^\perp$  as $y$ itself. As usual, when studying a set, it helps to look at the boundary, i.e., the "edge cases". The vectors $y$  which  *barely* qualify for being in $K^*$ are those for which $y^\perp $ contains a side of cone $K$ (if you rotate such $y$ slightly in a wrong direction, the line $y^\perp$ will cross through $K$). This is why the boundary of $K^*$ is formed by half-lines perpendicular to the boundary of $K$.

Comment: The diagram shows the case in two dimension, which can be analyzed graphically. But if we are talking about the high dimensional case, where $x$ is a vector of n-dimension, is that possible to figure out the structure of dual cone?

Comment: @user288609 The geometry is richer, but same idea applies: the dual cone is the intersection of closed half-spaces that contain $K$. Of those, it is enough to consider only half-spaces that *barely* contain $K$; i.e., such that $K$ meets the half-space boundary at points other than the vertex.